# Offline HTML / Jquery form - view input data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am pretty new with this so I will try to explain my situation to the best of my ability.

What I am attempting to do is create a form that has multiple input fields including text, dropdowns, and checkboxs. After the information is filled in I would like to click a submit button and have a new page populate only the fields that had data input or were modified. For instance, some fields may not apply and may not have data input every time. I would like to have only certain fields show up when certain radio buttons are selected but it is not crucial at this point. The document will be used offline only and must be able to be processed completely client side.

From my research it sounds like JQuery would likely be the best bet to accomplish this but Im not sure what function I should be using.

Here is the current code I am working with. The textarea is obviously wrong and just shows the raw code, The submit button generates a page like I want it to but it displays my actual form.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you have additional questions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

function displayHTML(form) {
  var inf = form.htmlArea.value;
  win = window.open(", ", 'popup', 'toolbar = no, status = no');
  win.document.write("" + inf + "");
}


</script>


</head>



<body id="main_body" >




<form>
  <textarea name="htmlArea" rows="50" cols="150">
  <H3>Data</H3>

  <ul >

                    <li id="li_4" >
        <label class="description" for="element_4">FIELD </label> 
        <span>
            <input id="element_4_1" name= "element_4_1" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="8" value=""/>
            <label>FIELD</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="element_4_2" name= "element_4_2" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="14" value=""/>
            <label>FIELD</label>
        </span> 
        </li>       <li id="li_1" >
        <label class="description" for="element_1">FIELD </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_1" name="element_1" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_2" >
        <label class="description" for="element_2">FIELD </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_2" name="element_2" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_3" >
        <label class="description" for="element_3">FIELD </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_3" name="element_3" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li class="section_break">
            <h3>Section Break</h3>
            <p></p>
        </li>       <li id="li_18" >
        <label class="description" for="element_18">FIELD</label>
        <div>
        <select class="element select medium" id="element_18" name="element_18"> 
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="1" >FIELD</option>
<option value="2" >FIELD</option>
<option value="3" >FIELD</option>
<option value="4" >FIELD</option>
<option value="5" >FIELD</option>
<option value="6" >FIELD</option>

        </select>
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_7" >
        <label class="description" for="element_7">FIELD </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_7" name="element_7" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_19" >
        <label class="description" for="element_19">FIELD </label>
        <div>
        <select class="element select medium" id="element_19" name="element_19"> 
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="1" >FIELD</option>
<option value="2" >FIELD</option>
<option value="3" >FIELD</option>
<option value="4" >FIELD</option>
<option value="5" >FIELD</option>
<option value="6" >FIELD</option>

        </select>
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_20" >
        <label class="description" for="element_20">FIELD </label>
        <span>
            <input id="element_20_1" name="element_20" class="element radio" type="radio" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_20_1">FIELD</label>
<input id="element_20_2" name="element_20" class="element radio" type="radio" value="2" />
<label class="choice" for="element_20_2">FIELD</label>

        </span> 
        </li>       <li id="li_6" >
        <label class="description" for="element_6">FIELD </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_6" name="element_6" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_21" >
        <label class="description" for="element_21">FIELD </label>
        <span>
            <input id="element_21_1" name="element_21_1" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_21_1">FIELD</label>
<input id="element_21_2" name="element_21_2" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_21_2">FIELD</label>
<input id="element_21_3" name="element_21_3" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_21_3">FIELD</label>
<input id="element_21_4" name="element_21_4" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_21_4">FIELD</label>
<input id="element_21_5" name="element_21_5" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_21_5">FIELD</label>
<input id="element_21_6" name="element_21_6" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_21_6">FIELD</label>

        </span> 
        </li>       <li id="li_9" >
        <label class="description" for="element_9">FIELD </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_9" name="element_9" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_22" >
        <label class="description" for="element_22">FIELD </label>
        <span>
            <input id="element_22_1" name="element_22_1" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_22_1">FIELD</label>
<input id="element_22_2" name="element_22_2" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_22_2">FIELD</label>
<input id="element_22_3" name="element_22_3" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_22_3">FIELD</label>
<input id="element_22_4" name="element_22_4" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_22_4">FIELD</label>
<input id="element_22_5" name="element_22_5" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_22_5">FIELD</label>
<input id="element_22_6" name="element_22_6" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_22_6">FIELD</label>
<input id="element_22_7" name="element_22_7" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_22_7">FIELD</label>
<input id="element_22_8" name="element_22_8" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_22_8">FIELD</label>
<input id="element_22_9" name="element_22_9" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_22_9">FIELD</label>

        </span> 
        </li>       <li id="li_8" >
        <label class="description" for="element_8">FIELD</label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_8" name="element_8" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_23" >
        <label class="description" for="element_23">FIELD </label>
        <span>
            <input id="element_23_1" name="element_23_1" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_23_1">FIELD</label>
<input id="element_23_2" name="element_23_2" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_23_2">FIELD</label>
<input id="element_23_3" name="element_23_3" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_23_3">FIELD</label>
<input id="element_23_4" name="element_23_4" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_23_4">FIELD</label>
<input id="element_23_5" name="element_23_5" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_23_5">FIELD</label>
<input id="element_23_6" name="element_23_6" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_23_6">FIELD</label>
<input id="element_23_7" name="element_23_7" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_23_7">FIELD</label>
<input id="element_23_8" name="element_23_8" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_23_8">FIELD</label>
<input id="element_23_9" name="element_23_9" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_23_9">FIELD</label>
<input id="element_23_10" name="element_23_10" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_23_10">FIELD</label>
<input id="element_23_11" name="element_23_11" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_23_11">FIELD</label>

        </span> 
        </li>       <li id="li_10" >
        <label class="description" for="element_10">FIELD </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_10" name="element_10" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_24" >
        <label class="description" for="element_24">FIELD  </label>
        <div>
        <select class="element select medium" id="element_24" name="element_24"> 
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="1" >FIELD</option>
<option value="2" >FIELD</option>
<option value="3" >FIELD</option>
<option value="4" >FIELD</option>
<option value="5" >FIELD</option>
<option value="6" >FIELD</option>
<option value="7" >FIELD</option>
<option value="8" >FIELD</option>
<option value="9" >FIELD</option>
<option value="10" >FIELD</option>
<option value="11" >FIELD</option>
<option value="12" >FIELD</option>

        </select>
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_14" >
        <label class="description" for="element_14">FIELD</label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_14" name="element_14" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_15" >
        <label class="description" for="element_15">FIELD </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_15" name="element_15" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_16" >
        <label class="description" for="element_16">FIELD </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_16" name="element_16" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_25" >
        <label class="description" for="element_25">FIELD </label>
        <div>
        <select class="element select medium" id="element_25" name="element_25"> 
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="1" >FIELD</option>
<option value="2" >FIELD</option>
<option value="3" >FIELD</option>
<option value="4" >FIELD</option>
<option value="5" >FIELD</option>
<option value="6" >FIELD</option>
<option value="7" >FIELD</option>
<option value="8" >FIELD</option>
<option value="9" >FIELD</option>
<option value="10" >FIELD</option>
<option value="11" >FIELD</option>
<option value="12" >FIELD</option>
<option value="13" >FIELD</option>

        </select>
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_17" >
        <label class="description" for="element_17">FIELD </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_17" name="element_17" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li class="section_break">
            <h3>Section Break</h3>
            <p></p>
        </li>       <li id="li_12" >
        <label class="description" for="element_12">FIELD </label>
        <div>
            <textarea id="element_12" name="element_12" class="element textarea medium"></textarea> 
        </div> 






</textarea>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value=" Work? " onclick="displayHTML(this.form)">
</form>    



</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: My advice is to consider each of those things individually and in detail.  Simply saying "I'm gonna use jquery" is not really an answer to anything.  You may find that jquery simplifies some of your needs but not others. No matter what, you will benefit from learning with a minimal test case.

Comment: I was hesitant to even post this here because I assumed I would receive a response like this from an expert like yourself. Maybe I have come to the wrong place for help.

Comment: "I'm gonna use JQuery" - While Im sure my code vocabulary makes me look like an idiot. I was mentioning what I found in my research.

"you will benefit from learning with a minimal test case" - I have successful creates and run a script to reply a single element textarea. I think my problem is pulling data from multiple fields. I am willing to research, I am just asking for a little guidance to material that is related to my request.

Comment: I'm not trying to position myself as an expert here, and I'm not trying to be glib. I am just saying that this is not the best place for general guidance. It's easily the best place for specific help for specific questions, though, so if you break your ideas into smaller demonstrable chunks and formulate a question around them, you will likely find that you both learn more and get lots of great feedback.